# Decode legacy regular expression: is it a look behind and look ahead?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm having a hard time reading a legacy Perl code with regex,

```
$string =~ m/^\(\?\<\!\\S\)/ && $string =~ m/\(\?\!\\S\)$/
```

I do understand the basic ideas of positive/negative look ahead/behind in regular expression,
but still, it's very confusing to me of the real intent here.

Can somebody explain a bit?
Thanks!

Comment: First step: don't escape regex special characters when you want ot use them.

Comment: Have you tried any online regex explainers? (e.g., http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)  You will notice that there is no lookahead or lookbehind in these regexes.

Comment: In other words, you need to escape a special character (for the regex engine) only when you want to represent it as a literal character.

Comment: @RayToal That regex explainer is based on the Perl module YAPE::Regex::Explain, which only supports the subset of Perl's regular expression syntax that was current with Perl 5.6, over 12 years ago.  It works for this situation, but isn't a good general solution anymore.

Comment: In fact, it fails to explain what `\Q` and `\E` do in Miller's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expressions in that ***legacy code*** can be reworked to be more clear:

```
$string =~ m{^\Q(?<!\S)\E} && $string =~ m{\Q(?!\S)\E$}
```

Basically, this matches a string that begins with the literal `'(?<!\S)'` and ends with the literal `'(?!\S)'`.  In fact, we can rework this logic to not use a regex at all:

```
substr($string, 0, 7) eq '(?<!\S)' && substr($string, -6) eq '(?!\S)'
```

Those literal strings themselves look like a regex negative look behind and look ahead assertions, but the regex is actually just trying to match the literal strings.

Comment: \Q..\E, don't see this used very much, but they do make for easier to read `regex` patterns.

Comment: @MattGreen It's a fairly common thing to use whenever someone is trying to match a literal string.  `$string =~ m/\Q$literal_string/`, but it's also a common mistake that programmers forget.

Comment: indeed, if you base your answer on the given pattern, the `\Q` `\E` seems to be appropriate, but I'm sure that the OP want really to use lookarounds.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Actually he doesn't want that at all.  He just wanted to understand that "*legacy code*"

Comment: The OP may not have meant it that way, but whoever wrote the regexes probably did.  Then someone ran them through a simple-minded procedure that "escaped" them by sticking a backslash (`\`) in front of every character that's not a word character.

Comment: @AlanMoore That's one theory, but then why would the anchors not be escaped?  Of course, why would they be there at all?  If they were assertions, they'd be looking beyond the start and end string anchors, which would be meaningless.  So who knows?  Not me.  Obviously we would be able to figure out intent if we saw more code, but I'm not interested in refactoring someone's legacy code.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This expression returns true if the variable `$string`  *begins* with the character sequence `(?<!\S)`, AND the variable *does not end with* the character sequence `(?!\S)`.

It appears to be code that is looking for strings that look like regexes beginning with negative lookbehinds and not ending with negative lookaheads.

So meta.

Comment: I think you misread that.  The `\S` was actually escaped as well: `\\S`. So it's not looking for a non-space character. It's actually just looking for the full literal string